# Comparing a wave's wavelength and the dimension of a medium in which the wave travels

Tags: waves, geometric-optics

Is making a comparison in between a wave's wavelength in a medium, and the medium's own lengthscale only useful when one needs to check whether the laws of geometrical optics are applicable? In other words, if one is concerned about physical (wave) optics, such comparisons make no sense?

Comment: Waves of the material in a material medium, (for e.g. water waves in water medium) do not make sense below a length scale where the continuum approximation of the medium is lost. I don't understand the connection to optics here.

Comment: If you mean using rays for the direction of the wave, rays assume that the medium is continuous down to the smallest scale, i.e. no structure..

Comment: Let's say we have two layers stacked vertically. The layers themselves are homogenous but the two-layer system is not. When a ray (represents a wave, be it acoustic, elastic or EM) is incident onto the boundary, effects like reflections/conversions happen. So in this sense the rays do see the structure, which in this case is that sharp boundary?

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, if one is concerned about physical (wave) optics, such comparisons make no sense?

Consider the case of fiber optics.

The ratio of the diameter of the fiber core to the wavelength of the optical signal is crucial to determining the modes that will be supported in the fiber, which has dramatic implications for the dispersion of a signal being sent along the fiber.

As a more specific example, 9-um core fiber is a common type of single-mode fiber used with infrared wavelengths (~1.3 or 1.5 um). But if used with visible light (for example, 0.68 um), it will no longer operate with a single mode, and will introduce substantial modal dispersion (the debate on whether modal dispersion should really be called "dispersion" should be left aside for another Q&A).

So yes, the relation between the optical wavelength and critical dimensions of the structure it's travelling through can be sensible and important.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am having a really hard time wrapping my head around this topic, just because I am not familiar with its theoretical basics. Do you have a reference, a pdf online or a chapter of a book, where you can point me to that discusses the general relationship of a wave's wavelength and the dimensions of the medium the wave travels in?

Comment: There is no general relation. You can shine whatever wavelength light or radio wave you want at whatever structure you want. But how the structure reflects/transmits/guides will depend very much on the ratio of wavelength to structure dimensions. For a reference, any textbook on electromagnetics will go through the math that gets to this result.

Comment: Will the relation (in between the medium's dimension and the wave's wavelength) influence the velocity of the wave? From wave equation, wave speeds do not have an explicit dependence on medium dimensions. So is it correct to say, if we have a wave who is unable to complete a whole cycle of oscillation in a medium (i.e. the wave's wavelength in that medium is much bigger than the medium's dimension), then the wave is still going to travel inside that medium with a velocity dictated by the thin medium's properties (tension, modulus etc.)?

Comment: Yes, but you're asking in such a general way that it's hard to explain why without just saying "go read a whole textbook". Sticking to the optical fiber example, you can  solve the differential equation boundary problem to get the form of the mode that can propagate along the fiber. This will have a $\beta_{eff}$ parameter that is related to the propagation velocity in the direction of the fiber axis, and depends (as far as I can recall) on the ratio of the light wavelength to the fiber diameter.

Comment: For some simpler geometry (i.e. slab waveguide) I'm more sure it's one-to-one from the ratio of wavelength to waveguide dimension. For the cylindrical waveguide (optical fiber) case I'm not 100% certain on this point.

Comment: Sorry but I am still not quite understanding. Are you saying that a wave's propagation speed will depend on the ratio of its wavelength and the medium's dimension? The physical situation I am thinking about is if we have two layers with different velocities, vertically stacked together. Say the bottom layer is a half-space with speed v1, and top layer is thin and finite with velocity v2. If you shoot two waves vertically up from the half-space, with the first wave's wavelength smaller than both layers dimensions (infinity for bottom half-space and L for the top "thin" layer),

Comment: then observing at the top of the "thin" layer, you will see it's traveling at speed v2. What if now you have a second wave, whose wavelength is entirely contained in the half-space, but is much bigger than the top "thin" layer, what velocity will you observe the wave is traveling on the top of the "thin" layer? Would it be some kind of an average between v1 and v2 (different weightings depend on the wavelength-medium dimension ratio)?

Comment: 1. The medium doesn't have a dimension. For example, "glass" doesn't have a dimension. A structure made out of a material has dimensions.

Comment: 2. If you want to ask about some particular structure, you should open a new question to ask about that. I tried to answer your very general question "does the propagation velocity depend on dimensions of the structure", and my answer is "in the case of waveguides it does". Now you're asking about something that doesn't sound like a waveguide...so it's more or less a completely new question.

Comment: 3. I'm not clear what you mean about "the velocity" of the wave in your 2-layer structure. Why do you think this structure would cause a wave to travel "on the top of the thin layer"? I would say that the wave incident from the lower half space just reflects back into the lower half space. The phase and magnitude of the reflection will depend on the ratio of the thickness of the thin layer to the wavelength (as well as the angle of incidence, the indices of the two materials, etc). You can research thin film filters to understand why.